# Bootstrapping Galera on RHEL7.2 systemctl: unrecognized option '--wsrep-new-cluster'

Tags: mariadb, systemd, rhel7, galera

I am trying to set up Galera cluster via Puppet and I have an additional (probably misguided) requirement to use "Red Hat supported" RPMs.  The problem I have due to this requirement is that bootstrap command: `systemctl start mysqld --wsrep-new-cluster` fails with the error:

```
systemctl: unrecognized option '--wsrep-new-cluster'
```

I am assuming that the RPM I am using, `mariadb-galera-server-5.5.42-5.el7ost.x86_64`, does not a very good `mariadb.service` file. I was hoping that `mysqld.service` (which is a symlink to `mariadb.service`) would accept the `--wsrep-new-cluster` option and start mysql/mariadb server with the `--wsrep-new-cluster` option, but it does not.

How should I modify the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.services` file to execute `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid --wsrep-new-cluster` when someone executes, `systemctl start mariadb --wsrep-new-cluster`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to fix the systemd stuff, *although it would be nice to know*. Instead I opted to craft my puppet manifest to perform the bootstrapping as per this web page: http://alesnosek.com/blog/2016/01/31/bootstrapping-a-galera-cluster-on-rhel7/

In summary of the blog entry above I need to do this:

1. Execute `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --wsrep-new-cluster` on the cluster's master.
2. Bring up the other nodes in the cluster by executing, `systemctl start mariadb`, on them.
3. Execute `pkill -SIGQUIT mysqld` on the master
4. Execute `systemctl start mariadb` on the master.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply bootsrapping master with `sudo galera_new_cluster`?

Comment: IIRC `galera_new_cluster` is not available until MariaDB >= 10.3

Answer (score 1):

5.5 is a rather old version; --wsrep-new-cluster is a rather new option.  Suggest you use a newer MariaDB.

Comment: Yes. Things work fine with the RPM's one can get from Maria DB (http://yum.mariadb.org/) but like I said on the OP I have a requirement to use a particular YUM repo where the latest version is "mariadb-galera-server-5.5.42-5.el7ost.x86_64"